# Best approach for setting ASMX Namespace for multiple services

Tags: c#, web-services, namespaces, asmx

I have a number of different ASMX services running on a single domain. Is the best approach to set a different namespaces for each service ?

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mydomain.com/MyXmlService/")]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mydomain.com/MyTestService/")]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mydomain.com/MyBookingService/")]
```

Is the following a recommended approach, even though the url `http://www.mydomain.com/MyXmlService/` doesn't point to the actual service which in this case is

```
http://www.mydomain.com/MyXmlService/Xml.asmx
```

Comment: You could use a "dummy" domain to make it clear that this is just an XML namespace (not an actual domain/host/server): `Namespace="http://services.mydomain.com/MyXmlService/"` and so on ... The XML namespace just **looks** like a URL - but it's really **just a name** - there's no link to anything that's actually existing at any of those "URL"'s ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mydomain.com")]
```

And if you're building these in a large organisation:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://www.mydomain.com/department")]
```

Comment: So all services would use the exact same namespace ? even though they are running as different applications.

Comment: If you only have three then yes. The service names themselves distinguish them. If you're likely to have more each in a separate department of your company then you can separate them with e.g. Loans, Insurance, Savings...